# Load image using imageWithContentsOfFile + GCD in table still slower than SDWebImage

Tags: objective-c, sdwebimage

I have been using SDWebImage's setImageWithURL... to load remote images on tableview. It is perfect.

Now I need to create a table of user saved images but since images are not remote, I cant use SDWebImage. Besides images are saved by user using [imageData writeToFile..] so I cant use imageNamed either.

I tried to use GCD (this code is part of a UIImageView+ category..):

```
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self setImage:image];
            [self setNeedsLayout];
        });
    });
```

It still feels much slower than a table of remote images managed by SDWebImage. Is there any way to handle cache/asynchronous loading of LOCAL images?